# python 3 can't concat bytes to str for a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, type-conversion, encode

I have the following chunk of code that I'm trying to run

```
import json
import textProcess as tp

review = open('../inres_review.json')
vocabulary = open('../vocabulary.txt','w+')
label = open('../label.txt','w+')
data = open('../data.txt','w+')

voc = []
revs = []
lab = []
dat = []
i=1
for line in review:
    jre = json.loads(line)
    jstar = jre['stars']  
    text = jre['text']  
    lab.append(jstar)
    ws = tp.removeStopPunc(text)
    revs.append(ws)
    voc += ws
    i += 1

for i in lab:
    label.write(str(i)+"\n")
print ("label created successfully!")

voc = list(set(voc))
print (len(voc))
print (type(i))
for i in voc:
    vocabulary.write(i.encode('UTF-8')+"\n")
print ("Vocabulary created successfully!")

for revid, rev in enumerate(revs):
    dat.append({})
    for w in rev:
        if w in voca:
            k = voca.index(w)+1
            if k not in dat[revid]:
                dat[revid][k] = 1
            else:
                dat[revid][k] += 1
print (len(revs))


for revid, rev in enumerate(dat):
    for k,v in rev.iteritems():
        s = str(revid+1)+' '+str(k)+' '+str(v)+'\n'
        data.write(s)
print ("successfully create data")


review.close()
vocabulary.close()
label.close()
data.close()
```

However, no matter what I changes I implement I am getting the following error. Can anyone please point out what's wrong here?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-21a3dc9eb8ad> in <module>()
     33 print (type(i))
     34 for i in bvoca:
---> 35         vocabulary.write(i.encode('UTF-8')+"\n")
     36 print ("successfully create vocabulary!")
     37 

TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The issues above have been fixed.. However when I run my code, looks like the last block of code is not getting executed because my data.txt file is blank, also the output doesn't print len(revs) and "successfully created data". Any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`encode` returns `bytes`, so you need to convert `'\n'` to `bytes` as well:

`i.encode('UTF-8') + b"\n"`

Comment: Thanks! looks like it fixed it. But now another error  has come up :



TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: @NidhiSirohi use `str(i.encode('UTF-8') + b"\n")` probably help.

Comment: Thanks @TanmayaMeher but I tried  the following : vocabulary = open('../vocabulary.txt','wb+') and it worked! :)

Comment: But... but... shouldn't you suggest just `open`ing the file with UTF-8 encoding? Then you don't have to bother about encoding later – just feed strings to the `write()` method.